# build php5.3.8 on ubuntu , get error: configure: error: Unable to locate gmp.h

Tags: php, ubuntu, build

I am using ubuntu 13.10 x64, and I'm trying build php 5.3.8, I downloaded the source code and run the configure:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data 
--with-tidy --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/conf 
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php/conf.d --enable-debug --with-openssl 
--with-kerberos --with-zlib --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-curlwrappers 
--with-enchant --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr 
--with-png-dir=/usr --with-vpx-dir=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-t1lib 
--enable-exif --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-gd-jis-conv --with-gettext 
--with-gmp --with-mhash --enable-intl --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mysql 
--with-mysqli --enable-pcntl --with-pdo-mysql --with-pdo-pgsql 
--with-pgsql --with-pspell --with-libedit --with-readline --enable-shmop 
--with-snmp --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvshm 
--with-xsl --enable-zip --with-pear --enable-zend-signals --enable-maintainer-zts
```

And I got this error: `configure: error: Unable to locate gmp.h`

I have installed `libgmp-dev` and `libgmp3-dev` use `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev` but still can't run the configure successfully, how can I fix this problem?

---

if I run `locate gmp.h` I can see it here:

```
/usr/include/linux/igmp.h
/usr/include/netinet/igmp.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12/include/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12/include/uapi/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-13/include/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-13/include/uapi/linux/igmp.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-13-generic/include/linux/igmp.h
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do you have gmp.h anywhere on the system? If it is installed on a non-standard location (or the standard location has changed since the release of php 5.3.8) GCC might be looking for it in the wrong path.

My advice would be to locate gmp.h and if it isn't at usr/include/gmp.h try to symlink to it.

In response to your comment (and since comments syntax highligher is limited).

try symlinking it

```
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h
```

if that fails, see if you can compile including the parameter

```
--with-gmp=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

give a look to the gcc documentation. It has a small section about gmp path.

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: Thank you @amenadiel , I runed `locate gmp.h`, please see my edit in my question.

Comment: try symlinking it 

  **ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/include/gmp.h**  

and, if that fails, see if you can compile including the parameter 

**--with-gmp= /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu**

Comment: The symlink did the trick, the *--with-gmp* option didn't work for me

Comment: if file /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h doesn't exists, try to run "apt-get install libgmp-dev"

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug.  I reported it -- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69993 -- and provided a patch to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this info, but the patch doesn't seem to fix it for me. Symlinking the header file does.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks. I didn't use the patch, but knowing that it was expecting gmp.h to be inside an `include` folder helped me to fix my issue.