# Php7 compilation errors with --with-t1lib

Tags: php, compilation

I'm trying to compile from source Php7 and I get only this warning (everything else seems fine)

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-t1lib
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987883/how-do-i-install-php-7-php-next-generation-on-ubuntu), the question is the same and the guy asking said it's a regression.
Is it still true?

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658248

If so this implies I can't use t1lib and ttf lib on ubuntu?

Here's my command line if you need it

```
/php-7.0.1# ./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc \
    --prefix=/usr --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-png-dir \
    --enable-exif --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-apxs2=/opt/httpd/bin/apxs \
    --with-freetype-dir --with-xpm-dir \
    --with-zlib-dir --with-openssl --enable-ftp \
    --with-mcrypt --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-libxml \
    --with-xsl --enable-pcntl \
    --with-curl=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.2.0 \
    --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
    --with-pdo-mysql  \
    --with-pdo-pgsql \
    --with-t1lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Warning message explains everything, when you want to include external extension to php you must first run  `./buildconf --force` then the new extension should be listed in options list.

Here you go.
1.Make sure that you have `t1lib` source files available in **ext** folder, If not you should move `t1lib` folder to **ext** folder.

2.Run `./buildconf --force`, Then make sure that `--with-t1lib` option is listed, run `./configre --help` to find out.

(if `./buildconf --force` fails to run, then you will need to install `autoconf`, it helps ./buildconf to scan php directory for config.m4 files which includes extension information and rebuild `configure` file)

3.You should be good to go!