# can't install php 7.1

Tags: php, installation, php-7.1

```
devall@giga:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.1 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1'
```

I am trying to install php 7.1 , tried almost everything...

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

reinstalled ubuntu twice.. still same error. #help

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?. Have you tried these other posts on StackOverflow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987883/how-do-i-install-php-7-php-next-generation-on-ubuntu

Comment: How about: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-php-70-or-php-71-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I am using 19.04 ubuntu

Comment: tried both solutions. It didn't work.

Comment: would using ubuntu 18.04 be an option, that could solve your issue,
if not, you can still compile php7.1 from the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with `software-properties-common`

```sh
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt search php7
sudo apt install php7.1
php -v
```

Comment: I just tried this and I am still getting the same error as OP, trying to install both PHP 7.1 and 7.2. Got the above error that it couldn't find 7.1, and when I tried to install 7.2, it installed 7.3 instead.

Comment: @EricaSummers, if you want to install multiple versions of php, you will be better off to use docker containers with one version for each container

Comment: I was not looking to install multiple versions, I was trying to get either 7.1 or 7.2 but for some reason it could only find and install 7.3, no earlier versions. I don't know if that was a recent change due to the latest 8 release or what reason it could be...